# Why can't I copy a section of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm new to java, but have done some programming in other languages before. I have an array that I declared. This one is for the basic equipment, and each of the basicSimple* have been correctly declared earlier on:

```
//Creating template...
Item[] basicSet = new Item[15];
basicSet [0] = basicSimpleShoes;
basicSet [2] = basicSimplePants;
basicSet [4] = basicSimpleShirt;
basicSet [6] = basicSimpleGloves;
```

I'm trying to copy the array to some other ones, each for one of the possible formats, one of which looks like this:

```
//Strongarm set...
Item[] strongarmBeginnerSet = new Item[15];
strongarmBeginnerSet [0,6] = basicSet[0,6];
strongarmBeginnerSet [9] = basicSimpleShortsword;
strongarmBeginnerSet [10] = basicSimpleShield;
```

Again, the basicSimple* Items are correctly declared earlier on. I keep on getting an error, something about a missing closing bracket, but I can't find where it is. Do I have to declare each piece individually or is there a function I'm unaware of for this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply won't work in Java, the slice notation exists for other programming languages (say, Python), but not in Java:

```
strongarmBeginnerSet[0,6] = basicSet[0,6]; // compiler reports a syntax error!
```

You have to copy each element in turn, like this (and I'm assuming that you intended to copy up to and including the seventh element located at index `6`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    strongarmBeginnerSet[i] = basicSet[i];
```

Or alternatively, use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
System.arraycopy(basicSet, 0, strongarmBeginnerSet, 0, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

`strongarmBeginnerSet [0,6] = basicSet[0,6];` is not valid syntax in Java. You will need to use a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

`strongarmBeginnerSet [0,6] = basicSet[0,6];` is invalid syntax for Java.

You could use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to achieve the same result...

Something like...

```
System.arraycopy(basicSet, 0, strongarmBeginnerSet, 0, 6);
```

For example...

Answer (score 0):

To copy a segment of the array use:

```
strongarmBeginnerSet [6] = Arrays.asList(basicSet).subList(0,7).toArray();
```